# How to run command on GUI boot

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, 20.04, automation

I have a raspberry pi 4 model b, it is running on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I want to start Firefox in kiosk mode on boot.

I've tried:

- @reboot in crontab
- creating a service to call the script
- adding the script to my .bash_profile

I have also chmod u+x the script

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox -kiosk 'http://google.com'
```

When I manually invoke the script in the command line it works without a problem.

I have not gotten any errors or issues, the script just doesn't appear to run

What is the magic sauce required to get a script to run on boot in Ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you can probably just add it as a startup application - just use that command. Open the application menu - the dots icon - and type in 'startup'. If it's not there then it's `sudo apt install gnome-startup-applications`. My Ubuntu VM is lacking Firefox so I didn't test it.

Comment: The display server starts *after* login. @reboot runs much too early. A .service file works...IF you get the target and user correct.  Look for your ~/config/autostart directory. That's what runs *after* the display server starts up, and that's where your script should go.